# navigation.navigate not working (not navigating to another screen)

Tags: react-native, navigation, expo, react-navigation, stack-navigator

I am using React Navigation 6,
Expo 48,
React Native 71.

I have tried using other functions like navigation.push() but no luck either. I also tried using getNavigation() instead of getting it from the props of the function but no luck either.

I'm not 100% sure if it navigation.navigate() is the problem since I didn't get anything in the output.

In the following part of my code, everything runs except for navigation.navigate() in the "imTired" function.

```js
  const imTired = (quiz) => {
    navigation2.navigate("Quiz", {
      host: index === 0 ? true : false,
      code: code,
      index: index,
      color: "#fff",
      qn: 15,
      comp: true,
      quiz: quiz,
    });
  };

  onSnapshot(doc(db, `Competitions/${code}`), (document) => {
    if (document.data().status === 1) {
      let quizz;
      quizzes.forEach((val, ind) => {
        if (val.Name === document.data().quiz) {
          quizz = val.Quiz;
        }
      });

      const quiz = [];
      const chosenIndexes = [];
      for (let i = 0; i < 17; i++) {
        let index = randomIntFromInterval(1, 51) - 1;

        if (chosenIndexes) {
          chosenIndexes.forEach((value, idx) => {
            while (value === index) {
              index = randomIntFromInterval(1, 51) - 1;
            }
          });
        }

        if (quizz[index].type === "multiple") {
          const rand = randomIntFromInterval(1, 3) - 1;
          const answers = [
            decode(quizz[index].incorrect_answers[0]),
            decode(quizz[index].incorrect_answers[1]),
          ];
          answers.splice(rand, 0, decode(quizz[index].correct_answer));
          quiz.push({
            qn: decode(quizz[index].question),
            q1: answers[0],
            q2: answers[1],
            q3: answers[2],
            ca: rand,
          });
        } else if (quizz[index].type === "boolean") {
          let caa;
          if (quizz[index].correct_answer === "True") {
            caa = 0;
          } else {
            caa = 1;
          }

          quiz.push({
            qn: decode(quizz[index].question),
            q1: "True",
            q2: "False",
            ca: caa,
          });
        }
      }
      imTired(quiz);
    }
  });
```

Here is my react navigation configuration (I think this is what you meant)

```js
<NavigationContainer theme={theme === "dark" ? DarkTheme : DefaultTheme}>
        <StatusBar
          style="auto"
          hideTransitionAnimation="slide"
          hidden={false}
        />
        <Stack.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerShadowVisible: false,
            gestureEnabled: false,
          }}
        >
          {waiting ? (
            <Stack.Screen
              name="Loading"
              component={Loading}
              options={{
                headerShown: false,
                animationEnabled: false,
              }}
            />
          ) : !loggedIn ? (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Fleap Academy"
                component={Landing}
                options={{
                  headerShown: false,
                  animationEnabled: false,
                }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Sign Up"
                component={Signup}
                options={{ title: null }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Log In"
                component={Login}
                options={{ title: "" }}
              />

              <Stack.Screen
                name="Forgot Password"
                component={Forgot}
                options={{ title: "" }}
              />
            </>
          ) : (
            <>
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Home"
                component={Tabs}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen
                name="Quiz Start"
                component={Start}
                options={{ headerShown: false }}
              />
              <Stack.Screen name="Friends" component={Friends} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Quiz" component={Quiz} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Learn" component={Learn} />
              <Stack.Screen name="Waiting Room" component={WaitingRoom} />
            </>
          )}
        </Stack.Navigator>
        <Toast />
      </NavigationContainer>
```

Every variable used is defined (I checked) and there was no errors in the terminal. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: where is `navigation2` coming from?

Comment: @VariabileAleatoria tried using `getNavigation()` to do the navigation so I made a variable called `navigation2`. (it didn't work)

Comment: can you share your navigator configuration? From which screen are you navigating? Have you ever defined a navigation listener somewhere?

Comment: @VariabileAleatoria I edited my post to include my navigator configuration. I am navigating from the screen labelled as "Waiting Room". No I do not have any defined navigation listeners.